# await till the end of exectuion of dynamically generated async code in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am creating an async python function during runtime. It can be created as a plain string / python ast object. Then I execute the code using `exec()`.

I want to run the generated code and wait till the execution ends for it. I generate the function, and then inejcting code so that the final code looks like this-

```py
import asyncio

async def my_app():
    # some async calls etc

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(my_app())
```

In my caller code, I am doing

```py
exec(my_code)
await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

I was having trouble doing `await my_app()` in the python code (caller is already an async function).
According to my understanding, the sleep(0) gives control to the event loop to process other tasks. But I am not sure how this will work out if the code generated makes multiple async calls (which it possibly will). How to assure the exectuon finished.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to generate code at runtime? What sort of code is it?

Comment: I am exploring the absurd amounts of power python is giving, I come from more of a C++ background and this just blows my mind.

Comment: But chances are you really don't want to generate code as text, but e.g. just compose (e.g. curried/partialed) async functions into e.g. `TaskGroup`s (new in Python 3.11) and run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really do need to: generate an async function, `exec` it in a namespace, grab the reference to the function, and run it as usual.

```
import asyncio

generated_code = """
import asyncio

async def my_app():
    print("hello!")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("hoi!")
    # some async calls etc

"""


async def go():
    ns = {}
    exec(generated_code, ns)
    my_task = asyncio.create_task(ns["my_app"]())
    await my_task


asyncio.run(go())
```

EDIT: Re the comments; instead of global variables, pass in an object to modify (a dataclass here for brevity's sake):

```
import asyncio
from dataclasses import dataclass

generated_code = """
import asyncio

async def my_app(state):
    print("hello!")
    state.age *= 2
    state.name = state.name[::-1]
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("hoi!")

"""


@dataclass
class MyState:
    name: str
    age: int


async def go():
    state = MyState(name="Arthur", age=42)
    ns = {}
    exec(generated_code, ns)
    print("State before", state)
    my_task = asyncio.create_task(ns["my_app"](state))
    await my_task
    print("State after", state)


asyncio.run(go())
```

This outputs

```
State before MyState(name='Arthur', age=42)
hello!
hoi!
State after MyState(name='ruhtrA', age=84)
```

Comment: I also want to set some global variables and then get updated values after executing the function (changed inside the function). How can i do that?
i was using the naemspace to extract them, hence want everything to finish inside the exec() call

Comment: Global variables are a bad idea. If you need to modify state, then have your function accept that state as an argument, modify it, and read the changes out afterwards.

Comment: @W1nTer003 Please see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
import asyncio

async def my_app():
    #Your dynamically generated async code here even it can contain multiple async calls
my_code = generate_dynamic_code()
asyncio.run(my_app())
```

asyncio.run() will run the my_app() function, which contains your dynamically generated async code. You don't need to use await asyncio.sleep(0) or manually create an event loop and task; asyncio.run() simplifies this for you.